# How to get input data in a Vue form?

Tags: vue.js

I have the following component:

```
<template>
  <div>    
    <form @submit.prevent="formSubmit()">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="amount">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%">Buy</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</template>
     
<script>

export default {

  props:{


  },


  computed: {
    amount() {
      return this.$store.getters.amount
    },
  },
  methods: {
      formSubmit() {
          let currentObj = this;
          
          console.log(this.amount)

          axios.post('MY-BACKEND', {        
              amount: this.amount,

          },

          .then(function (response) {
            currentObj.output = response.data;
          }.bind(this))

          .catch(function (error) {
              currentObj.output = error;
          });
      },
  
  }
}

</script>
```

This is a standard form with an input text field. The problem with my code is that when i input the field, the value of `amount` is not what i input into the field, but it is always the default value that `this.$store.getters.coinBalance` sets it to. So suppose that when i load the component the value of `amount` is `60` and i input in the field `120`, the value of `amount` stays `60`. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the `amount` from the store but you didn't update it when your input changes. To update the `amount` value in the store, you can create a [setter for your computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter):

```js
computed: {
  amount: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.getters.amount
    },
    set(val) {
      this.$store.commit('updateAmount', val)
    }
  },
},
```

And in your store create a mutation `updateAmount` to update `amount`:

```js
updateAmount(state, amount) {
  state.amount = amount
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I already have a mutation to update it, but what i mean is that: can i get the value of amount i input in the field without having to call the mutation?

Comment: You can bind the amount to a data property, i.e. have something like `data() { return { amount: 60 } }` and remove computed `amount`, but then the changes won't be updated in the store.

Comment: Ok! I tried this, but the value of amount keeps staying the same. Suppose when i open the page the default value of amount is 100, if i input into the input text field "5" and i hit the Buy button, the value should be the one i input but instead it's still 100

Comment: *the value should be the one i input but instead it's still 100*, which value is this ? Did you get the value from the store or it's the local `amount` value ?

Comment: I'm guessing you should still use the mutation other wise you wouldn't need the `amount` state in the store in the first place. But I'm not completely sure about your logic.

Comment: I know i  was not very specific, so let me try to explain it a little bit better: i have this input text field and i want to show as a default value into the text field the amount that the user has, so i get that amount from the store when the page is opened. Then the user can input a different amount into the input field, submit the form and send a post request to my backend to do stuff

Comment: I don't want to change the store value, i only want to get the value of amount that the user inputs and send a post request with that amount

Comment: Hmm, when you say *the value should be the one i input but instead it's still 100*, it seems you are using the value outside the component, which means you might need a store.

Comment: If you can create a reproducible example with jsfiddle or codepen, I might help you better. But now I'm not completely sure what the issue is. `data` approach should work, or maybe you forget to remove the computed `amount` ?

Comment: I don't need to update the store. In this case the store is only used to retrieve a default value for amount so that i can show it to the user, but when the form button is hit, i need to send a post request with the value that was input into the field by the user, not the value of amount from the store

Comment: If all you need is a default value, you can initialize `amount` in created lifecycle, i.e. `created() { this.amount = this.$store.getters['amount'] }`. No need for computed property.

Comment: Indeed, i needed a created lifecycle